# How do I set a version 7.0 bing map center to a location

Tags: bing-maps

I am using version 7.0 of the Bing Maps API. After creating the map, an array of pins are pushed into the EntityCollection object of the map class. Next, I want to center the map so that all of these pins are viewed on the map. The map's zoom is large enough to accommodate this. In the previous version, map.setMapView() was used, but BING Maps 7.0 has erased this function.

Some code for relevance:

```
map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), mapOptions);
map.getCredentials(function(credentials) {
    var searchRequest = 'https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/' + address + '?output=json&jsonp=getLatLong&key=' + credentials;
    var mapscript = document.createElement('script');
    mapscript.type = 'text/javascript';
    mapscript.src = searchRequest;
    document.getElementById('myMap').appendChild(mapscript);
});
function getLatLong(json){
findPlaceResults = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(json.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[0], json.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[1]);
myShape = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(findPlaceResults);
//...
var pins = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < AllLocations.length; i++) {
    var shape = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(AllLocations[i].Latitude, AllLocations[i].Longitude);
    var pins = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(shape);
    map.entities.push(pins);
}
map.entities.push(myShape);
if (map.entities.getLength() > 0) {
    //map.SetMapView(pins);
}
```

Code TLDR: Stuff happens, try to SetMapView, doesn't work.

Any thoughts would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer at this website http://www.i-programmer.info/projects/131-mapping-a-gis/1609-getting-started-with-bing-maps-ajax-control-70.html?start=1

"If you are familiar with earlier versions of the Map object you need to know that the new version has far fewer methods. The idea is that instead of having lots of methods the new control has a few methods that accept complex objects as a parameter that specifies lots of settings.

For example, the  original map control's SetCenter method will move the map location to the specified latitude and longitude. The new V7 map control has a setView method which accepts a ViewOptions object which in turn has a center property that can be set to a Location object which specifies the center of the map."

Answer (score 3):

When you creating your pins you need to create helper array will that lead to your goal.

```
Create array that contains all the locations converted to Microsoft location objects.
    // The array
    var arrLocations= [];

    for (var i = 0; i < AllLocations.length; i++) {
        var shape = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(AllLocations[i].Latitude,AllLocations[i].Longitude);
        // You add those two lines.
        var yourLocation= new Microsoft.Maps.Location(AllLocations[i].Latitude,AllLocations[i].Longitude);
        arrLocations.push(yourLocation);
        var pins = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(shape);
        map.entities.push(pins);
    }
```

Now you use bing maps feature that gives you best zoom and pointing according to given locations.(The LocationRect)

```
var bestView = Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromLocations(arrLocations);
```

Then you set the map view according to the best view that we found.

```
 setTimeout((function () {
        map.setView({ bounds: bestView });
    }).bind(this), 1000);
```